# msg! macro throws out of memory

Tags: solana-program, memory

I would like to log the initializer_key field (which is a Pubkey)

```
   msg!("{}", ctx.accounts.escrow_account.initializer_key.clone());
```

and I got the following
error

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete 
    Program 6Datvm1dQHKsR9VTKt7R3W6yjVFLctQW3SmF7CcyF2KT invoke [1]
    Program log: Instruction: Liquidate
    Program log: Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There's really not enough information here to tell you. You can see from the error message that you're out of memory but including the `msg` is not sufficient to diagnose

Comment: looks like you are running out of heap memory. the `msg` macro uses `format` when called with arguments which takes up some heap some. Try to unbox some of the accounts and data and if its not possible, try to request for more heap using `RequestHeapFrame` instruction.